# aws Unable to execute HTTP request: Broken pipe (Write failed) when try to upload from test containder to localstack container s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, clojure, localstack

I tried to use docker container (localstack) to simulate the S3 and upload a file to it. Below are my code:

```
(ns com.my.service.resources.s3
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :refer [error info infof]]
            [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:import
   [java.io File FileInputStream FileOutputStream]
   java.util.UUID
   [com.amazonaws ClientConfiguration]
   [com.amazonaws Protocol]
   [com.amazonaws.services.s3 AmazonS3Client AmazonS3URI]
   [com.amazonaws.services.s3.model DeleteObjectRequest
    GetObjectRequest ObjectMetadata PutObjectRequest]
   [com.amazonaws.services.s3.model AmazonS3Exception]))


(defn- s3-client
  []
  (let [client-configuration (ClientConfiguration.)
    s3-client (AmazonS3Client. client-configuration)]
(.setEndpoint s3-client "http://localstack:4566")
s3-client))

(defn upload
  "Upload a given file to s3 and return the path"
  [id user file filename size content-type]
  (metrics/time
   @registry
   {"operation" "upload" "service" "s3"}
   (let [key (str BASE "/" user "/" id ".tmp")
         size (.length file)
         content-type "application/shapefile"
         in (FileInputStream. file)
         metadata (doto (ObjectMetadata.)
                    (.setContentDisposition filename)
                    (.setContentLength size)
                    (.setContentType content-type))
         request (PutObjectRequest. BUCKET key in metadata)]
     (try
       (infof "uploading to s3://%s/%s" BUCKET key)
       (.putObject (s3-client) request)
       (format "s3://%s/%s" BUCKET key)
       (finally
         (try
           (.close in)
           (catch Exception ex nil)))))))
```

However, when I tried to upload a 8k file from the test container to the localstack container (I have created the bucket in the localstack containder), I got error below:

> com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Broken pipe (Write failed)\n\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1219)\n\tat

One thing I noticed I ran

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4566 s3 ls
```

At very beginning (before I ran the code), I can see the bucket on the localstack without errors. Then, after I ran the code, I got the above error. So I tried to run `aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4566 s3 ls` again, it gives me following error:

```
An error occurred (503) when calling the ListBuckets operation (reached max retries: 4): Service Unavailable
```

And if I exit the container and returned using `docker exec -it -w /tmp /test /bin/bash` again, I will be able to see the container again. That makes me think somehow, my code is NOT right (pipeline broken) and stuck on the test container side.

My containers were simply booted using `docker-compose up`. Below are my yaml file

```yaml
localstack:
  image: xxx.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hub/localstack/localstack:latest
  container_name: localstack
  ports:
    - "4566:4566"
  environment:
    - SERVICES=s3
    - DEBUG=1
    - DATA_DIR=
    - AWS_REGION=us-east-1
    - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=fake
    - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=fake
    - HOSTNAME=localstack
    - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localstack
  volumes:
    - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

test:
  image: xxx.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/build-images/build-image:0.12.0
  container_name: test
  environment:
    - AWS_REGION=us-east-1
    - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=myAccessKeyId
    - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=mySecretAccessKey
    - JAVA_OPTS=-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=
    - ARTIFACTORY_SVC_ACCT_PWD=${ARTIFACTORY_SVC_ACCT_PWD}
    - ARTIFACTORY_SVC_ACCT=${ARTIFACTORY_SVC_ACCT}
  ports:
    - "46050:46050"
  volumes:
    - .:/tmp
  depends_on:
    - db
  entrypoint:
    - tail
    - -f
    - /dev/null
```

Any idea why my code failed ans stuck the test container? Thanks

Comment: How big is your file? And have you tried retrying this? Does it always error?

Comment: The file is only 8k. And yes, I tried 4, 5 times and each time, it failed with this error.

Comment: Your script won't work as `nc` isn't found on it; instead of the script, use the AWS CLI to do `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 ls` to rule out LocalStack or your code.

Comment: I did what you suggested - running bucket list from test container, and get an error `An error occurred (500) when calling the ListBuckets operation (reached max retries: 4): Internal Server Error`

Comment: So it's not your code that's failing but LocalStack in general. How are you running it? Any logs from the container?

Comment: Updated the question with the info of docker container booting up.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, when I tried again to list the bucket on localstack from test container, I got "Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4566/"". Please note this time, I tried it immeidately after the containers were booted.

Comment: @Laodao Just in case - if you need LocalStack only for S3, consider using MinIO. In my experience, it's much better - much faster, not prone to issues after updates, better adherence to the AWS spec.